# Invalid credentials error requesting oauth2 token from PayPal API

Tags: api, paypal

I am using the PayPal REST API for the first time and trying to get an authentication token but keep getting an "Invalid credentials error".

I am following Step 2 in the documentation found here:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/

I am using the Chrome extension "Advanced rest client"

Here are the values entered in the rest client:

**Header:**
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept:application/json

**Form data**
grant_type:client_credentials
clientId:ASF6RRBP0uTq7FnC90tpFx7vfA-Pliw8uQDjv5RZ10Y_NVspuc88pUPLN6yM
secret: EAdx7BDKzWczDomYG2QDHu8jhaAXj4xDZLHadvL5aRfesjwo5c81zbSpRxuE

When I send the request I get the following error:
{
error: "invalid_client"
error_description: "Invalid client credentials"
}

Can anyone help me to figure what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Form data should only contain

`grant_type=client_credentials`

and then add header

`Authorization: Basic put base64of(clientid:secret)here`

don't pass **client id** and **secret** in form data.